# Socket.io issue with next js

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js, socket.io, next.js14

I'm working on integrating a notification service using `socket.io` and `socket.io-client` in a `Next.js 14` project. Initially, my implementation was working fine, but I've started encountering a connection refused error that I can't seem to resolve. The error message I'm receiving is:

> GET http://localhost:3005/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OvjwIvr net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Below are the relevant parts of my code:

Server Setup - `server.js`:

```
import { connectToDatabase } from "../src/db/dbConfig";
const http = require('http');
const { Server } = require('socket.io');

const server = http.createServer();
let connectedClients = [];

const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: process.env.DOMAIN,
        // methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }
});

io.on('connection', async (socket) => {
    console.log('Client connected');
    connectedClients.push(socket.id);

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('Client disconnected');
        connectedClients = connectedClients.filter((s) => s.id !== socket.id);
    });

    socket.on('test', async (data) => {
        const { db } = await connectToDatabase();
        const changeStream = db.collection("notifications").watch();
        changeStream.on("change", function (change) {
            if (change.operationType === "insert") {
                const newRecord = change.fullDocument;
                const message = JSON.stringify({ type: "newRecord", data: newRecord });
                // omitted for brevity
            }
        });
        io.emit('test', { message: data.message });
    });
});

server.listen(3005, () => {
    console.log('Socket.IO server listening on port 3005');
});
```

Context Setup - `SocketContext.js`:

```
// use client
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

export const SocketContext = React.createContext();

export const SocketContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (socket == null) {
            const socketIo = io.connect('http://localhost:3005', {
                reconnectionDelay: 1000,
                reconnection: true,
                reconnectionAttempts: 10,
                agent: false,
                upgrade: false,
                rejectUnauthorized: false,
            });

            setSocket(socketIo);

            return () => {
                socketIo.disconnect();
            };
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <SocketContext.Provider value={{ socket }}>
            {children}
        </SocketContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

Despite ensuring that the server is running and accessible, and having configured `CORS` properly (as far as I can tell), I'm still facing this `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` issue. I've tried various troubleshooting steps such as checking for port conflicts and ensuring that the environment variable for the domain is correctly set, but the problem persists.

Has anyone faced a similar issue or can spot something I'm missing in my setup? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.